# kotlin property initializer execution in JUnit tests

Tags: junit, kotlin

I have an abstract base class for testing in Kotlin:

```
abstract class TestBase(){
  protected var session = configure()

  private fun configure() {
    ...
    return session // a live session object
  }

  @After
  open fun tearDown() {
    ...
    session.close()
  }
}
```

Then in the derived test class, we have

```
class MyTest: TestBase() {
  ...
  @Test
  fun testScenario1() {
    ... // uses the live session object
    assertTrue(myCondition_1)
  }

  @Test
  fun testScenario2() {
    ... // uses the live session object
    assertTrue(myCondition_2)
  }
}
```

When I first saw this code, I thought that this will be problematic since if `session` is only executed once in the initialization part, it will be closed after the first test is run. And during the 2nd test, since `session` has been closed, it will throw exception. However, the code runs with no problem. When I traced it, I saw that the initialization block was run for each test. In other words, `session` was initialized for each test.

My question is why? Is this the behavior behind JUnit that for each test, it will run the whole initializer plus the constructor of the class?

If this is the case, why use the `@Before` annotation? Can't we just put all the `@Before` code in the initializer block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, JUnit creates a new instance of the class for each test. `@Before` method is invoked after the constructor.

> Can't we just put all the @Before code in the initializer block

Yes, you can (in the constructor for Java). It's more for symmetry with `@After`.